# Unable to auto-complete native python libraries from file in subdirectory

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm having trouble with Eclipse PyDev autocomplete when trying to use an `import` statement in a file in a subfolder.

My folder structure is:

```
src
--data
--libs
  --__init__.py
  --myclass.py
--logs
mainscript.py
```

When I use `import` in mainscript.py (i.e. `import re`) everything goes fine, however when I try to use `import` in myclass.py eclipse doesn't show the autocomplete display.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well actually I just realized that it works pasting it manually. Anyway is there a way to solve it?